# Catching the sound played with vlcj

Tags: java, audio, javasound, vlcj, mixer

After few reseach and many problems with the different audio formats, I'm trying to use [vlcj](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj). For playing sounds, it seems to be perfect. 
But, to follow [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379912/taking-control-of-the-soundcard-with-java) I've asked, I'd like to catch the sound played in vlcj.

Someone told me that it's impossible for JavaSound to catch the sound played out of the JVM. Ok. But how to do with a sound played in the JVM, using vlcj ?

vlcj have methods to set the volume. But I didn't found anything to get the "level output" or to catch the sound and mix it with another sound for example.

Does someone may help me again ? Thank you very much.

Here is a very simple example of a player using vlcj, just with the help of the firsts tutorials.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;

public class SimplePlayer {
private final JFrame frame;
private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;
private String[] playList = new String [] {
        "Donna Summer - Last Dance.mp3",
        "Bon Jovi - Bed Of Roses - YouTube.mp3",
        "Sam Brown - Stop (Official Music Video) - YouTube.mp3",
        };

public SimplePlayer() {
    frame = new JFrame("My First Media Player");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(playList[2]);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new SimplePlayer();
        }
    });       
}    
}
```

Comment: *"Someone told me that it's impossible for JavaSound to catch the sound played out of the JVM."*  You should be more careful who you listen to.  Sometimes it is possible, other times not.  As an aside, had you tried playing the tracks using the Java-FX based `MediaPlayer`?  I find it works well with MP3s (have not tried other types).

Comment: Isn't this essentially a dupe of your other question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362049/getting-the-audio-level-with-vlcj

Comment: With the example you posted the audio is not played by the JVM, it's played natively by VLC. So you can't "catch" it in Java.  It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do - you want access to the raw audio sample buffer before it's played so you can modify it? And then what, play it? Or save it to disk?

Comment: For Java-FX, I tried but as noticed in the Oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm), it can read MP3, but not the other formats.  And my aim is to create a mixing console in JAVA with, physical lines in (microphones, DAT...) and "inside" line in (sound played via a java application or other applications). All those "lines in" will be mixed to go to the physical outputs (heaphone, speakers, audio recorder...). So, yes, I want to access to the raw audio. Maybe the interface DirectAudioPlayer in vlcj may help but, how to use it ?